# How to install Adobe Reader X in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, wine, 64-bit, pdf, adobe-reader

I want to install Adobe Reader X (10 or 11) in my system. But there is no native application available for Linux. After doing Google I have seen that Adobe Reader 10.1.14 is given gold rating with Wine 1.5.19. But when I have tried, the installation is going fine without any error, but I could not find the Adobe Reader in menu. So I have tried it through PlayOnLinux and getting error that "wine crashed". I really need the Adobe Reader x as Adobe Reader 9 does not support lots of commenting and writing tools of Adobe Reader x. Please help me to install it.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. I have tried to install Adobe Reader 10.1.14 and 11.0.01 with Wine 1.4 and 1.5.19 through PlayOnLinux.

Comment: There is lot of alternative PDF readers for Ubuntu, sure some of them will support the features you like.

Comment: I have tried to find, but could not. pdfedit used to work before (though it does not have very good interface) but is not available for ubuntu 12.10. Also tried flpsed and scribus, but could not find any option like commenting, highlighting or strike out some word. If you know any good such pdf reader or editor please let me know.

Comment: This looks as something you could use http://lifehacker.com/5875879/the-best-pdf-viewer-for-linux

Comment: I don't think except Adobe Reader (acroread), any other reader provides plug-in for in-browser PDF reading. (Google Chrome - comes with in-built  PDF reader though). PDF Edit is the best pdf editor which actually works (more or less).

Comment: If you need features like commenting, highlighting etc. try [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/): `sudo apt-get install xournal`

Comment: I am also unable to install it in Wine. Adobe has decided not to support Linux any more. If you are able to run Windows in a virtual machine, I think that that may be your only viable option (VirtualBox with Seamless Mode is a good suggestion).

Comment: @tikend I hvae tried Okuler, it do not have all the functionality I need.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE Xournal dose not contain those features.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice I don't need plug-in for in-browser reading. I already have acroread 9. pdf editor is the best option but, sadly it is not working in 12.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Foxit reader with wine working perfect. It has all the feature that I am looking for. Installing flawlessly and working like a native linux app.

Comment: The problem I had with Foxit Reader: lack of support for various character sets when inserting comments, etc. Does it have any feature that you can't find in PDF-XChange Viewer?

Comment: I have installed both, so I will compare and get back.

Comment: Though other option like comment and strike out and underline is there. Options like replace or insert text are not coming, also the type writer is not giving me any option to change the font, font size and font color. Since I am using English only so I don't know about character support.

Comment: Thanks, it seems not much has changed since I last compared them. **PDF-XChange Viewer** has **many more features**, including **international character set support** for text input like comments, typewriter mode, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can accept this as a valid answer, but since what you want is **a feature-rich PDF viewer program** with "*lots of commenting and writing tools of Adobe Reader x*" I think you would be very happy with **[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)**.

It actually offers **more features** than Acrobat Reader using a **much smaller disk space and memory**!

You can either install it under **Wine** or - if you encounter any installation problems -simply download the Portable version and then create your own Launcher manually.

I've been using it with various versions of Ubuntu and Wine for a long-time, including the current Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and the latest Wine version.

## UPDATE

The new **[PDF-XChange Editor](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor)** (which supersedes the *PDF-XChange Viewer*) **works better under Wine** with more or less the same features in the **Free** version.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. PDF-Xchange Viewer is providing almost all the fun features, also it working fine with wine. But still it is not as good as Adobe Reader X

Comment: I've stopped using it long time ago, but it seems a number of previously non-existent features have finally been added. Is there any important feature missing in PDF-XChange Viewer?

Comment: It has almost all feature, but some feature are reserved for pro user only.

Comment: It's really upsetting to me when people suggest other programs rather than just answering the question.  I am looking for a method of installing Adobe reader using Wine because I have PDFs that can ONLY be opened with Adobe Reader, and suggestions like this get in the way of honest, productive discussion.

Comment: @AveryFreeman I fully understand you, and that's why actually my answer  starts by saying "I'm not sure if you can accept this as a valid answer..." But it is a fact that some cases like this are very problematic, leading virtually to no solution, where an alternative path might be suggested to meet the need. Unfortunately, some PDFs that can ONLY be opened with Adobe Reader are a pain in the neck :-( I'm also interested in finding a way to install it under Wine, but no way :-( You see, even **Apurba** had to settle with Foxit Reader ;-)

Comment: I have a dual boot system so I ended up rebooting into Windows and installing Adobe Reader DC - Flash was also required, grr - and exporting the files, then rebooting into Debian where I do all my work.  Thankfully I do not encounter those files often.  This issue is quite frustrating, but I think the framework required for those files (DC + Flash) is so complicated, nothing less than a Windows VM or partition will work.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with this question for years. I need to run Adobe Reader because it has features that the EU government requires for editing complicated forms and those features are only available in versions later than 10.x - which are not supported on linux.

I finally found [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/) article that described how to download and install free and legal virtual machines with WindowsXP that run under VirtualBox. Together with [this](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.03/en_US/AdbeRdr11003_en_US.exe) free download of Adobe Reader for XP it all now works!!

Comment: Nice!!.  The link in the article to download Windows XP mode is broken, use this one https://www.askvg.com/direct-download-link-official-links-to-download-windows-xp-mode-and-windows-virtual-pc-for-windows-7/  Also to install VirtualBox on Linux checkout their Linux downloads page https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: To extract the .exe downloaded file you need `p7zip` package, `apt-get install p7zip` then to extract run the command `7za x WindowsXPMode_es-es.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is still interest on this topic. I just installed Adobe Reader DC.
First I tried just using plain wine... It did not work. Do not despair...:)
Using PlayOnLinux and selecting Install -> Acrobat Reader DC
You need to download the windows version at Adobe. Then just follow the installation and you ill be set to go

Comment: I wonder if this will work for Flash-framework PDF files, as well... hmm...