# Acroread can't edit annotations: Commenting Not Allowed

Tags: wine, pdf, adobe-reader

I started annotating a pdf on a windows machine but then I wanted to make some changes on my Linux machine later. I have the native Linux acroread 9 installed which *can* do comments but there's a 50% chance a given document is locked or in some way broken and in `File->Properties->Security`, `Commenting: Not Allowed` (for that matter this might happen with the latest versions too, not sure). I also run into huge performance issues when viewing comments (extreme, and I mean *extreme*, lag on a decent PC).

So I thought I'd try a newer version of Adobe reader under wine. This did not work out at all (as of July 2014) with the installer failing to create any files or crashing at launch when copying from a windows install.

How can I reliably add/edit annotations to PDFs on linux, yet allow all those non-techie people who use the windows and Adobe reader to see and interact with them?

Answer (score 0):

I've found any of the following work well:

- Installing the windows version of `foxit` (another pdf reader) with `wine`, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/251109/196639), worked without issue. No irrational "Commenting Not Allowed" nonsense. Upon saving, i can see the updates with the linux acroread straight away.
- Install VirtualBox (or another emulator), windows, and the latest windows version of adobe reader. Though this is pretty heavy duty for a small task like commenting.